# CSS3 animation continue from last position

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have CSS3 animation that moves element x position from 0 to 100% and 100% to 200%, but when it moves from 100% to 200% it doesn't move from 100% it moves from 0% to 200%.

```
@keyframes moveZero {
  0%{
    transform: translate(0%, 0px);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate(0%, 0px);
  }
}

@keyframes moveOne {
  0%{
    transform: translate(0%, 0px);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate(100%, 0px);
  }
}

@keyframes moveTwo {
  0%{
    transform: translate(0%, 0px);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate(200%, 0px);
  }
}
```

Please check my [jsfiddle for full working example](https://jsfiddle.net/fj8g1xhe/6/)

Comment: There's a mistake in you code I assume. Should be `@keyframes moveTwo {
  0%{
    transform: translate(100%, 0px);
  } ...`

Comment: Here you need in jQuery to know what position you already are. It's all right to go from pos2 to pos3 changing your CSS but then when you go from pos1 to pos3 it's gonna glitch and fly to pos2 without any animation. You also need this because you want an animation when going to pos 3 to 1 ( that has no animation atm ) or from pos 2 to pos 3 ( that glitches to pos1 then animates to pos 2 ).

Comment: @Relisora how can I do this animation with javascript?

Answer (score 1):

### CSS Only

Here's a pure CSS solution:

(Markup has been simplified from your case to provide a simpler example)

http://jsbin.com/kimibojedi/

**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <input type="radio" name="radios" id="one"/>
  <label for="one" class="nav__button">Button One</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radios" id="two"/>
  <label for="two" class="nav__button">Button Two</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radios" id="three"/>
  <label for="three" class="nav__button">Button Three</label>
  <div class="nav__bottom"></div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 450px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav__button {
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .3s;
}

.nav__bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(240, 20, 40);
  bottom: 0;
  transition: .3s;
}

input[type="radio"] { display: none }

input[type="radio"]:checked + label { background-color: pink; }

input[type="radio"]:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .nav__bottom{
  left: 0;  
}

input[type="radio"]:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .nav__bottom{
  left: 150px;  
}

input[type="radio"]:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .nav__bottom{
  left: 300px;  
}
```

You can use the labels to select hidden radio elements, and use the `:checked` pseudo-selector in conjunction with the `~` sibling selector.

### Javascript suggestions

Otherwise, a couple recommendations on the solution you posted below:

Using `33%`, `66%`, etc, won't be as exact as you may need it to be (for instance, 33% width at 66% left will leave you with a 1% gap). I prefer to set up the math and let the browser do the finessing for the pixels:

```
left: (100 / 3) + '%' // 33.3333...%
```

I've also found it much easier to deal with transitions in my CSS as much as possible. That's where all the logic for layout goes, so I prefer to keep it separate from javascript. But, we often need javascript to make changes that will affect layout. I like to do this by adding classes in Javascript and letting the CSS take over from there. For instance:

```
// JS
$('button').click(function() {
   $('.nav__bar').addClass('active');
})

// CSS
.nav__bar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0px;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  transition: .5s;
}

.nav__bar.active {
  width: 100%; 
}
```

I've made a fork of your JSFiddle here that uses this approach: https://jsfiddle.net/hp681kbu/

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution with jQuery, with CSS it impossible to track current values animated properties, but Javascript can track. so I have done small change in my code, I remove all my CSS animation part and just add one line `transition: 0.5s`

```
.main__nav{
  &__ul{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
  }
  &__li{
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    background-color: #004d85;
    display:inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    font: 12px;
    height: 44px;
    line-height: 44px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  &__button{
    color: #fff;
    background: #004d85;
    border: none;
  }
  .animator__span{
    position: absolute;bottom: 0;left: 0;
    width: 33%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;    
    transition: 0.5s; /* added */
  }
}
```

and change my javascript to

```
     switch (index) {
        case 0:
          animatedBorder.css({
            'left': '0px'
          });
          break;
        case 1:
          animatedBorder.css({
            'left': '33%'
          });

          break;
        case 2:
          animatedBorder.css({
            'left': '66%'
          });
          break;
        default:
          animatedBorder.css({
            'left': '0px'
          });
      }
```

to let jQuery to animate the x value.

Comment: You can do it with CSS, but then you need to use transitions and not animations